# Weak compactness is to trees as [?] is to lattices?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, order-theory, lattice-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal. Recall that $\kappa$ is [weakly compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_compact_cardinal) if every tree of height $\kappa$ has either a level of size $\kappa$ or a branch of size $\kappa$.

So if $\kappa$ is a weakly compact cardinal, one has some way of controlling the behavior of trees of size $\kappa$.

**Question 1:** Are there analogous large cardinal properties which allow one to control the behavior of posets which are not trees? For example, complete Boolean algebras? Distributive lattices?

**Question 2:** Alternatively, can the tree property already be used to control the size of more general posets, such as lattices?

What I would like is to know that if I have a nice lattice $L$ of cardinality $\leq \kappa$, then under some condition on $\kappa$, there are properties of $L$ which I can check, among which would be the condition of having no $\kappa$-sized branch, implying that $L$ is in fact of cardinality $<\kappa$.

Comment: In the case of distributive lattices, such large cardinal notions have been discussed here. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249370/is-this-property-a-new-large-cardinal-notion

Comment: And there are various characterizations of the notion of a weakly compact and that of a strongly compact cardinal in terms of a large cardinal version of the Boolean prime ideal theorem.

Comment: @JosephVanName Thanks! I will have to think about how that notion fits in here. I was anticipating that one would need a _stronger_ large cardinal property to do the sort of thing I have in mind, but there the question seems to be about _weakening_ weak compactness. I wonder if there is anything in the literature related to that MO post...

Comment: See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.200410033